# Question was closed for three or four different reasons, does it make sense to just show one?

Tags: discussion, close-reasons

I just added the fifth close vote to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30393176/convert-existing-android-application-to-website?noredirect=1), the other four close votes were I think 2x too broad, and 2x unclear. Or maybe it was 2x too broad and 1x unclear and one more that I don't remember. Either way, I close voted based on the reason that it was asking for an off-site resource (library), however

1. It is now showing my name in relation to "**put on hold** as too broad by [...] David Mulder"
2. If it was 2x too broad, 2x unclear and 1x off-topic, why is it showing up as only too broad? I noticed that that's the case already once before with a different question.

Personally I don't think the question is too broad at all, so it kinda irks me that it is presented the way it is. Additionally it is likely not going to help the user improve their posts either. Oddly enough I couldn't find any discussions on meta about these kind of situations. They aren't that rare are they?

Comment: Note that close reasons could change after edits to the question

Comment: This is probably the definitive Meta.SE feature request: [Distinguish close votes by reason](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/54917/distinguish-close-votes-by-reason)